# Php Array Index Not Work

Tags: php

Why My Script Not Work In Local USbwebserver

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in F:\Danyial\USBWebserver
>   v8.5\root\supportify\test.php on line 4

And Its Working On MY Server Side

```
<?php

//why its not work
if(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select count(*) from gatwaylog"))[0]==0){
    echo 'hi';
}

//and why it work
$data=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select count(*) from gatwaylog"));
if($data[0]==0){
    echo 'hi';
}

?>
```

Comment: Why you don't check your PHP versions ? PHP5.3 behavior...

Comment: We Dont Use Newer Version Beacuse if I used New Version They Lost seesion after header (location:http://www.example.com)

Answer (score 2):

Array dereferencing isn't supported in php version <= 5.3 (*)

As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

As of PHP 5.5 it is possible to array dereference an array literal.

Comment: Too lazy to explain. +1 :)

Comment: We Dont Use Newer Version Beacuse if I used New Version They Lost seesion after header (location:http://www.example.com)

Comment: don't forget to check the correct answer, this will mark the question as solved